# How to ensure that a column won't get overriden by a null value?

Tags: storio

Let's say I have a simple `user` table with the following columns: `name`, `id`, `token`. I get these values from a server so whenever I get them I want to update it inside my local database.

Sometimes `token` is given to me and in those cases update `token`. Other times token will be null and in those cases I just want to keep the existing value inside `token`.

One way I thought of was to make a put resolver. Inside the put resolver, I check if the `user` given from the server has a value for token.  If it doesn't, I do a get based on the user's `id`. If i get a user back, I grab the token (from the user I got from the local db) and save that along with the new `user` info.

But won't that basically double the amount of time to insert? I was wondering if there was a quicker way.

P.S. I asked this question over at the GitHub page but realized it may be more appropriate to have it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment you can do this with custom `PutResolver` where you can implement `Put` operation as you need.

We also [working on annotation support](https://github.com/pushtorefresh/storio/issues/595) for our annotation processor so it'll be able to skip writing null values.